# C# logic to find offset and fetch values

Tags: c#

I get the below resultset from a SQL query and I store it in var.

```
+-----------+--------+
| Rownumber |  Data  |
+-----------+--------+
|         0 |      9 |
|         1 |      0 |
|         2 |      4 |
|         3 |      9 |
|         4 |     15 |
|         5 |      2 |
|         6 |      1 |
|         7 |      6 |
|         8 |      0 |
|         9 |      4 |
|        10 |      1 |
|        11 |      1 |
|        12 |      1 |
|        13 |      1 |
|        14 |      1 |
|        15 |      1 |
|        16 |      1 |
|        17 |      1 |
|        18 |      1 |
|        19 |      1 |
|        20 |      1 |
|        21 |      1 |
|        22 |      1 |
+-----------+--------+
```

I want to write a logic in c# :

I want to add the `Data` column sequentially.

If the summed `Data` column value is more than or equal to 15, then I want to store the following value in two variables:

- offset = The starting point of rownumber
- Fetch = Num of rows taken to achieve the sum 15

E.g:

**Iteration 1:**

```
+-----------+--------+
| Rownumber |  Data  |
+-----------+--------+
|         0 |      9 |
|         1 |      0 |
|         2 |      4 |
|         3 |      9 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Expected variable values:

- offset = 0
- Fetch = 4 (num of rows taken to achieve the value of 15. Sum of value should be >= 15)

**Iteration 2 :**

```
+-----------+--------+
| Rownumber |  Data  |
+-----------+--------+
|         4 |     15 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Expected values:

- offset = 4
- Fetch = 1 (num of rows taken to achieve the value of 15)

**Iteration 3:**

```
+-----------+--------+
| Rownumber |  Data  |
+-----------+--------+
|         5 |      2 |
|         6 |      1 |
|         7 |      6 |
|         8 |      0 |
|         9 |      4 |
|        10 |      1 |
|        11 |      1 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Expected values:

- offset = 5
- Fetch = 7 (num of rows taken to achieve the value of 15)

The iteration will go on until the last value.

Comment: So what is the code you have written so far? This is not a coding engine..

Comment: You should be atleast sharing your code you have written till now for others to understand your thought process for the given problem to help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed your model look like the following

```
public class Data
{
    public int Rownumber { get; set; }
    public int data { get; set; }
}
public class Result
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int fetsh { get; set; }
}
```

and you  need the following code

```
public List<Result> GetResults(List<Data> data)
{
    var sum = 0;
    var start_taking_index = 0;

    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();
 
   for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += data[i].data;

        if(sum >= 15 || i == data.Count-1)
        {
            // if the sum exceed 15 create new result
            results.Add(new Result
            {
                offset = start_taking_index,
                fetsh = i - start_taking_index +1,
            });
            // then reset the tracking variables
            start_taking_index = i+1;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

here is xUnit test the scenario in the question

```
[Fact]
public void GetResults_test()
{
    List<Data> datas = new List<Data>()
    {
        new Data{Rownumber =  0,data= 9},
        new Data{Rownumber =  1,data= 0},
        new Data{Rownumber =  2,data= 4},
        new Data{Rownumber =  3,data= 9},
        new Data{Rownumber =  4,data=15},
        new Data{Rownumber =  5,data= 2},
        new Data{Rownumber =  6,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber =  7,data= 6},
        new Data{Rownumber =  8,data= 0},
        new Data{Rownumber =  9,data= 4},
        new Data{Rownumber = 10,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 11,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 12,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 13,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 14,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 15,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 16,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 17,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 18,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 19,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 20,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 21,data= 1},
        new Data{Rownumber = 22,data= 1},
    };

    var result = GetResults(datas);


    Assert.NotEmpty(result);
    // first 
    Assert.Equal(0,result[0].offset);
    Assert.Equal(4,result[0].fetsh);
    // second
    Assert.Equal(4, result[1].offset);
    Assert.Equal(1, result[1].fetsh);
    // 
    Assert.Equal(5, result[2].offset);
    Assert.Equal(7, result[2].fetsh);
    // 
    Assert.Equal(12, result[3].offset);
    Assert.Equal(11, result[3].fetsh);
    // total count count
    Assert.Equal(4, result.Count);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Data> datas = new List<Data>()
        {
            new Data{Rownumber =  0,data= 9},
            new Data{Rownumber =  1,data= 0},
            new Data{Rownumber =  2,data= 4},
            new Data{Rownumber =  3,data= 9},
            new Data{Rownumber =  4,data=15},
            new Data{Rownumber =  5,data= 2},
            new Data{Rownumber =  6,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber =  7,data= 6},
            new Data{Rownumber =  8,data= 0},
            new Data{Rownumber =  9,data= 4},
            new Data{Rownumber = 10,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 11,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 12,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 13,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 14,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 15,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 16,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 17,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 18,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 19,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 20,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 21,data= 1},
            new Data{Rownumber = 22,data= 1},
        };
                        
        foreach(var entry in Calculate(datas))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Offset: " + entry.Key + " | Fetch: " + entry.Value);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Calculate(List<Data> data)
    {
        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        int offset = 0, lastOffset = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        
        foreach(var entry in data)
        {
            sum += entry.data;
            if(sum >= 15)
            {                   
                result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(lastOffset, offset - lastOffset + 1));
                sum = 0;
                lastOffset = offset + 1;
            }
            offset++;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public class Data
    {
        public int Rownumber { get; set; }
        public int data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mind that it does not have any guards - it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Linq` may do trick for you with `Skip` and `TakeWhile` extension methods:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Fill source info
    var source = new List<(int, int)>();    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 22; i++)
        source.Add((i, i switch
        {
            0 => 9,
            1 or 8 => 0,
            2 or 9 => 4,
            3 => 9,
            4 => 15,
            5 => 2,
            7 => 6,
            _ => 1,
        }));

    // Fetching result
    foreach (var (offset, fetch) in GetResult(source))
        Console.WriteLine($"Offset: {offset} | Fetch: {fetch}");

    // Output:
    // Offset: 0 | Fetch: 4
    // Offset: 4 | Fetch: 1
    // Offset: 5 | Fetch: 7
    // Offset: 12 | Fetch: 11

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static List<(int, int)> GetResult(List<(int, int)> source)
{
    var result = new List<(int, int)>();
    var proceededRecords = 0;

    while (proceededRecords < source.Count)
    {
        var offset = proceededRecords;
        var dataSum = 0;
        var fetch = source.Skip(proceededRecords).TakeWhile((data, _) =>
        {
            if (dataSum >= 15)
                return false;

            dataSum += data.Item2;
            return true;
        }).Count();

        proceededRecords += fetch;
        result.Add((offset, fetch));
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Remarks.**

I used tuples to simplify example and avoid creating some `Model` class with `RowNumber` and `Data` properties or `Result` class with `Offset` and `Fetch` properties.

The idea was to loop over source collection with taking some unknown amount of tuples until sum of **2nd** value in tuple is less than 15. `TakeWhile` help me with that. `Skip` was used to... skip amount of already fetched records.

Answer (score 0):

While your example shows that your data indexes are sequential and start at zero, it was not stated explicitely that it will be always the case.

This solution works even if the index of the data from your database is not starting from 0, or is not sequencial (or both). Or if instead of an index you had any other kind of identifier, such as a timestamp for instance.

i.e. if your data is like

```
+-----------+--------+
| Rownumber |  Data  |
+-----------+--------
|         6 |      1 |
|         7 |      6 |
|         8 |      0 |
|         9 |      4 |
etc...
+-----------+--------+
```

or

```
+-----------+--------+
| Rownumber |  Data  |
+-----------+--------
|        16 |      1 |
|         7 |      6 |
|       108 |      0 |
|         9 |      4 |
|      1910 |      1 |
|       121 |      1 |
etc..
+-----------+--------+
```

or even

```
+-----------------------+--------+
|        Timestamp      |  Data  |
+-----------------------+--------+
| 2021/03/02 - 10:06:24 |      1 |
| 2021/03/02 - 12:13:03 |      6 |
| 2021/03/04 - 02:48:57 |      0 |
| 2021/05/23 - 23:38:17 |      4 |
etc...
+-----------------------+--------+
```

Here is the part of the code actually doing the work. It does not really add complexity compared to a solution that would work only on zero starting sequencial indexes:

```cs
var Results = new List<Result>();
var Group = new List<Data>();
var Sum = 0;
var CurrentIndex = 0;

while (Source.Any())
{
    CurrentIndex = 0;
    Sum = 0;
    while (Sum < 15 && CurrentIndex < Source.Count)
    {
        Sum += Source[CurrentIndex].Value;
        CurrentIndex++;
    }
    Group = Source.Take(CurrentIndex).ToList();
    Source = Source.Skip(CurrentIndex).ToList();
    Results.Add(new Result 
    { 
        Root = Group.First().Index,
        Fetch = Group.Count
    });
}
```

What it does is rather simple:

It enumerates the first elements of your collection (source) while their sum is inferior to 15 (and there is still some elements to enumerate).

It counts the number of elements just enumerated (the fetch) and get the index of the first element (the root).

It then constructs a new collection by removing the elements that were just enumerated, and starts again, using that new collection until there is no more elements to enumerate.

That is all.

*The Group variable could be avoided alltogether. It would give the following code. I prefered keeping it in my example as it shows that the group itself could be used to perform any kind of operation on its content if needed.*

```cs
while (Source.Any())
{
    CurrentIndex = 0;
    Sum = 0;

    while (Sum < 15 && CurrentIndex < Source.Count)
    {
        Sum += Source[CurrentIndex].Value;
        CurrentIndex++;
    }

    Results.Add(new Result
    {
        Root = Source.First().Index,
        Fetch = CurrentIndex
    });
    Source = Source.Skip(CurrentIndex).ToList();
}
```

*By the way, the second nested while loop could be avoided by using Linq, see below. However this Linq query is particular and should be used with caution.*

*The TakeWhile method is using an unpure lambda, i.e. the lambda relies on external data: the captured variable Sum.*

*While this works perfectly fine, be aware that generally this kind of Linq query could lead to problems further down the road. For instance adding .AsParallel() to such kind of query would not work at all.*

```
while (Source.Any())
{
    Sum = 0;
    Group = Source.TakeWhile(e =>
    {
        if (Sum < 15)
        {
            Sum += e.Value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).ToList();

    Results.Add(new Result
    {
        Root = Group.First().Index,
        Fetch = Group.Count
    });

    Source = Source.Skip(Group.Count).ToList();
}
```

Here is the complete code, as a full runnable Linqpad query, with randomly generated data:

```cs
void Main()
{
    // Random data set preparation.
    var Rnd = new Random();
    
    var NonSequencialIndexes = Enumerable
        .Range(100, 300)
        .Where(i => Rnd.Next(2) == 1)
        .OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Take(30)
        .ToArray();
    
    var Source = Enumerable
        .Range(0, 30)
        .Select(i => new Data
        {
            Index = NonSequencialIndexes[i],
            Value = Rnd.Next(16)
        })
        .ToList()
        .Dump("Random data set");
    
    // Actual code
    var Results = new List<Result>();
    var Group = new List<Data>();
    var Sum = 0;
    var CurrentIndex = 0;
    
    while (Source.Any())
    {
        CurrentIndex = 0;
        Sum = 0;
        while (Sum < 15 && CurrentIndex < Source.Count)
        {
            Sum += Source[CurrentIndex].Value;
            CurrentIndex++;
        }
        Group = Source.Take(CurrentIndex).ToList();
        Source = Source.Skip(CurrentIndex).ToList();
        Results.Add(new Result 
        { 
            Root = Group.First().Index,
            Fetch = Group.Count
        });
    }
    
    // Display results
    Results.Dump("Results");
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public class Data
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class Result
{
    public int Root { get; set; }
    public int Fetch { get; set; }
}
```

An example of result:

```
+------+-------+
| Root | Fetch |
+------+-------+
|  346 |     3 |
+------+-------+
|  121 |     3 |
+------+-------+
|  381 |     2 |
+------+-------+
|  110 |     2 |
+------+-------+
|  334 |     2 |
+------+-------+
|  226 |     2 |
+------+-------+
|  148 |     2 |
+------+-------+
|  114 |     3 |
+------+-------+
|  397 |     3 |
+------+-------+
|  274 |     3 |
+------+-------+
|  135 |     3 |
+------+-------+
|  386 |     2 |
+------+-------+
```

for this data collection

```
+-------+------+
| Index | Value|
+-------+------+
|   346 |     0|
+-------+------+
|   294 |    14|
+-------+------+
|   152 |    11|
+-------+------+
|   121 |     3|
+-------+------+
|   234 |     6|
+-------+------+
|   393 |    13|
+-------+------+
|   381 |     8|
+-------+------+
|   305 |    15|
+-------+------+
|   110 |    13|
+-------+------+
|   357 |     9|
+-------+------+
|   334 |     8|
+-------+------+
|   214 |    13|
+-------+------+
|   226 |     6|
+-------+------+
|   248 |    15|
+-------+------+
|   148 |    12|
+-------+------+
|   131 |     9|
+-------+------+
|   114 |     3|
+-------+------+
|   250 |     4|
+-------+------+
|   217 |    11|
+-------+------+
|   397 |     3|
+-------+------+
|   312 |     7|
+-------+------+
|   191 |     7|
+-------+------+
|   274 |     7|
+-------+------+
|   292 |     6|
+-------+------+
|   277 |    14|
+-------+------+
|   135 |     2|
+-------+------+
|   240 |    12|
+-------+------+
|   163 |    12|
+-------+------+
|   386 |    12|
+-------+------+
|   330 |     5|
+-------+------+
```